# How to change the content of a file which is included in different scripts?

Tags: javascript, php, html, include

I am making a website for which I have to make the page active attributes on different lines for different pages. Now I put the whole common script inside a file header and include it in every script. Now how can I change the content of a line when including it on different pages?

The header is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="islamic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
     html,body
     {
          height: 1500px;
     }
    .grey
      {
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <!-- We are going to make this page for navigation purpose -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role = "navigation">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                         <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"> </span>

                    </button>
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">ILM</a>
               </div>

               <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                         <li ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                         <li ><a href="why.php">Discuss</a></li>
                         <li ><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                         <li ><a href="contacts.php">Contact</a></li>
                         <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Social <b class="caret"> </b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li> <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Linked IN</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#">You Tube</a></li>
                          </ul>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
        </nav>
```

I want to change the line

```
<li ><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
```

to

```
<li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

for home page.
Now I want to change the line

```
<li ><a href="aboutus.php" >About Us</a></li>
```

to

```
<li class="active"><a href="aboutus.php">Home</a></li>
```

for about us page.
Is it possible in php?

Comment: What type of the website is this? I mean when you click the menu like home, about, contact, discuss or anyother will the full page reload or it is partial reload?

Comment: Full page should be loaded. It is the navigation bar. Now on moving to the different pages I want different items to be active.

Answer (score 0):

you can try somethign like this

http://jsfiddle.net/habo/arjw2q6b/

Place this code at the end of your `</body>` tag.
Guessing your page Urls will have the anchor tags hrefs. one each page load after full document id read your script will check if the URL contains "index.php" or all other hrefs and if it does then it will call the function `resetActiveTab` that function will remove active class for all the list items (`li`) and add `class=active` for the current page

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.href.contains("index.php")){
        resetActiveTab("index.php");
    }
    else if(window.location.href.contains("why.php")){
        resetActiveTab("why.php");
    }
    else if(window.location.href.contains("aboutus.php")){
        resetActiveTab("aboutus.php");
    }
 }
function resetActiveTab(mySelector){
    $(".navbar-nav li").each(function( key, value ) {
    //alert($(value).attr("class"));
     $(value).removeClass("active");
       if( $(value).find("a").attr("href") == mySelector){
           $(value).addClass("active");
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: updted my answer. FYI: you need to add jQuery reference to your <head>